# How do I change fan speed for all my graphics cards?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, amd-graphics

I'm running an ethereum mining server, using claymore miner on Ubuntu 14.04. Usually it ends up crashing because one or two of my four GPU's gets too hot and stops. I can use `DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 100"`

to control the first GPU, but as soon as I change it to

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 /usr/bin/aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 100"
DISPLAY=:1 /usr/bin/aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 100"
```

or practically any other combo it returns

```
ati_pplib_cmd: Unable to open display `:0.1'.

/usr/bin/aticonfig: parsing the command-line failed.
```

I've already run `$ sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial` and I'm using the latest fglrx-updates.

`aticonfig --list-adapters`returns

```
* 0. 01:00.0 AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series 
1. 03:00.0 AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series 
2. 05:00.0 AMD Radeon R9 200 / HD 7900 Series
3. 07:00.0 AMD Radeon R9 200 / HD 7900 Series

* - Default adapter
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.